# Compare entered password to stored password

Tags: javascript, passwords

I have created a form signup which you create a password.  I then compare the entered password & email to the stored password & email for a successful login.  I am having an issue of getting an email address of undefined for the stored email. I'm sure it is something simple.  Below is my code -

```
const memberSignUp = (event) => {
  let formData = {
    firstName: document.getElementById("firstName").value,
    lastName: document.getElementById("lastName").value,
    email: document.getElementById("userEmail").value,
    password: document.getElementById("userPassword").value,
  };
  localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(formData));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("formData"));
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Account successfully created");
  window.location = "landing.html";
};

function clearForm() {
  document.getElementById("firstName").value = "";
  document.getElementById("lastName").value = "";
  document.getElementById("userEmail").value = "";
  document.getElementById("userPassword").value = "";
}

function memberSignIn() {
  let storedEmail = $("#storedEmail").val();
  let storedPassword = $("#storedPassword").val();
  let enteredEmail = $("#memberEmail").val();
  let enteredPassword = $("#memberPassword").val();
  console.log(storedEmail, enteredEmail);
  if (enteredEmail == storedEmail && enteredPassword == storedPassword) {
    alert("Login successful.");
    window.location = "index.html";
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect username or password.");
    window.location = "landing.html?#";
  }
}
```

My HTML code is below.  Thanks for checking.

```
<div class="forms-container">
  <form id="signInForm" onsubmit="return memberSignIn()">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="memberEmail"
        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
        placeholder="Email"
      />
      <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">
        We'll never share your email with anyone else.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        class="form-control"
        id="memberPassword"
        placeholder="Password"
      />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Sign In</button>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <p>
        New to Rewind?
        <a href="#" class="" target="_self" id="signUpButton"
          >Sign up now</a
        >
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <form class="row g-3" onsubmit="memberSignUp(event), clearForm()">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        class="form-control"
        id="firstName"
        placeholder="First"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="lastName"
        class="form-control"
        id="lastName"
        placeholder="Last"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="userEmail"
        placeholder="Email"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        class="form-control"
        id="userPassword"
        placeholder="Submit"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML as well? Chances are that `document.getElementById("userEmail").value` doesn't correspond with the html element. Make sure that there are no typos in the ID.

Comment: I can't see your HTML code and how you are getting the info from sessionStorage. Without it we can't help you.